# iOS 8 TableView Custom Cell with label and textfield

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

1) I have a custom cell that has a label and textfield in it for tableView. 
Im using a NSMutableDictionary for the label and texts.  There is NO button to go to another page, I want the editing to be done right in the tableView screen.   I have a couple errors I have been messing with but can't see what I am missing.  1: setting cells label, which is named in func before. 2: setting text field.  ERRORS marked in CODE section

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSArray *cellTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"weight",@"bf",@"lbm",@"neck",nil];// Make an ordered array of strings for the cell titles.
return [cellTitles count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Create a cell & register it for dequeing

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
measurementCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Set the cell's label:
cell.label.text = cellTitles[indexPath.row]; 
//ERROR!!!: USE OF UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER 'cellTitles'  

// Prepping the text field
// 1. Set the text field's delegate to be this view controller
// 2. Find out if there's an existing string for it to display in the self.dictOfLabelsAndText. If not, set it to be empty.
cell.textField.delegate = self;

NSString *key = cell.label.text;

if ([self.dictOfLabelsAndText valueForKey:key] != nil) {
    cell.textField.text = [self.dictOfLabelsAndText valueForKey:cell.needTitle.text]; 
//ERROR!!!: PROPERTY 'needTitle' NOT FOUND ON OBJECT OF TYPE 'measurementCell*'
} else {
    cell.textField.text = @"";
}

return cell;
}
```

2) Also from here I want to be able to add the inputed textfield information to core data that is linked to a specific date and id. Is that possible to do? Retrieving display would be with the possibility of using that date and id.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

1. declare the NSArray *cellTitles in .h file.
2. declare needTitle as property in you measurementCell class

Comment: You haven't needed to synthesize properties (and in fact you shouldn't do this) for the past 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. Declare NSArray in Interface section. and add Property to it.
2. Synthesise Property array in Implementation Section.